# Date Conversion error in VB6

Tags: vb6, date-conversion

If user entered date as 1st june 2011 (01/06/2011) in dd/mm/yyyy format

after conversion it returns “6th jan 2011” instead o f “1st june 2011”.

Let me explain how it converts it in 1st jan 2011.

```
User entered = 01/06/2011 (dd/mm/yyyy)   i.e. 1st june 2011
After conversion it returns = 01/06/2011 (mm/dd/yyyy) i.e. 6th jan 2011
```

Remember: user date format is not known at design time. it is being fetched from database and stored in a variable (string)

Is there any solution of it.

Please provide the solution related to VB6 only NOT in .net

Comment: If the user date format is not known, how do you know that the user meant june 1st and not january 6th?

Comment: while testing we got the user format from database which is "dd/mm/yyyy" and stored it in a variable. The reason I said that the user format is not know at design time, is just because any suggestion from any expert should not be based on assumption that the date format will always be "dd/mm/yyyy". it could be different format too.

Comment: Do you know anything about the structure of the format string? Can it be "yyyy-mm-dd", "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"...?

Comment: yeah it doesn't include time format. So it could be "dd/mm/yyyy" / "yyyy/dd/mm" or "yyyy/mm/dd" or anything else

Comment: Then only reliable solution is just parse user entered string into tokens and build date from them. Involves some text processing (try with Latvian date for example :)) Another way would be force user to enter all date parts separately; you can build UI according to format stored.

Comment: cannot force the user to enter date parts separately as application exist with approved GUI. I would appreciate if you can provide code to break the date based on format(stored in variable) and generate new date (in mm/dd/yyyy) format

Comment: You say "after conversion" - what conversion are you doing and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine I had written my own method to break the date into tokens as I found no other method to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to find the users regional date format setting:

```
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long
Private Const LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT = &H400
Private Const LOCALE_SSHORTDATE = &H1F ' short date format string
Private Const LOCALE_SLONGDATE = &H20 ' long date format string

Public Function GetUserShortDateFormat() As String
    Dim strLocale As String
    Dim lngRet As Long

    'Get short date format
    strLocale = Space(255)
    lngRet = GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SSHORTDATE, strLocale, Len(strLocale))
    strLocale = Left(strLocale, lngRet - 1)

    GetUserShortDateFormat = strLocale
End Function
```

But this won't guarantee that the user actually *entered* it in this format.

If you read a date from a database date column field into a date variable it will be in this format however.